# ExpressJS and AWS Lambda - Piping a GET response to a .zip breaks

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a function on AWS Lambda the purpose of which is to fetch a .zip from a REST API, extract its contents, and then display its contents with another viewer app. I'm using expressjs for routing, and I'm using the `request` module to handle the requests.

My app.js looks similar to this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var r = request(queryURL); // Where queryURL is a get request to fetch a .zip file

    r.on('response', function(response) {
        response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/testFile.zip'))
            .on('close', function() {
                res.send('Test message');
        })
    })
})

module.exports = app;
```

The problem seems to be with `response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(...));`
I can fetch an unrelated `html` and pipe that into `/tmp/testFile.html` and render it with `res.sendFile('/tmp/testFile.html')` just fine. I can even fetch individual images from the same API. But something about the .zip files breaks things.

This all works when run locally, but when I upload it to lambda it breaks, rendering `{"message": "Internal server error"}` on the browser. I have no idea how to access logs - I upload my function using ClaudiaJS.

Here is my handler function, in case that might be relevant:

```
'use strict'
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express')
const app = require('./app')
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app)
exports.handler = (event, context) => awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out how to access the cloudwatch logs and realized that Lambda was timing out. I changed the timeout from 3 seconds to 30 seconds and it has worked fine since.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues using the native https for pipe. After i saw you answer, I tried out using Axios + https://stackoverflow.com/a/47217305/4922074 and it worked!