# Unable to download zip file using axios

Tags: node.js, zip, axios

This is the code I use:

```
axios.get(fileUrl, {headers:{'X-API-TOKEN':xxxxxx})
```

Response data received is in binary, Which I am converting to base64 and saving in file. 
After saving zip file. If I try to open the file, it says invalid zip error.

Comment: Can you download the zip via the browser and see if the same error occurs?

Comment: I tried it in postman. it is working fine in postman.

Comment: One trick I've used is to get the request working in Postman (which you've done), then click the 'Code' button in the mid-right corner of Postman, which will generate a code snippet to perform the current request in various languages - including Node. There isn't an Axios-specific option, but there are several Node options which will give you some into on the correct configuration.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can try adding responseType as arraybuffer

```
axios.get(
   fileUrl,
   {headers:{'X-API-TOKEN':xxxxx}, responseType: 'arraybuffer'}
);
```

Comment: adding responseType: 'arraybuffer' worked fine for me.